# TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable' Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, error-handling

I'm trying to write a program that will open a text file from the web consisting of 10,000 words, then 'clean' the file to get rid of nonsense words, such as 'aa'. I eventually want to use these words to do other things so I want to add the non 'non-sense' words to be put into a new list. Every time i try to run this I run into the error code `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`.

```
import urllib.request  

def readWordList():  

response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000")
html = response.read()
data = html.decode('utf-8').split()

return data

clean = readWordList() 

def clean(aList):   
    newList = []
    for word in aList: 
        if range(len(word)) >= 2:
            newList.append(word)
    return newList


clean(clean)
```

Comment: Please fix your indenting, and include your full traceback.

Comment: `clean(clean)`? You can't use the same name for both a function and a list..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make up your mind: is `clean` supposed to be a list or a function?  You started as a list, but then replaced that with a function, and then told the function to clean itself.  Try this:

```
dirty_list = readWordList()
def clean(aList):
...

clean(dirty_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a variable called `clean`, immediately overwrite the name by declaring a function with the same name, then pass the function `clean` to itself.

Either change the function name, or the variable above with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you make a variable called `clean` and then you make a function called `clean` and finally you tried to use the function in the variable, both called `clean`. You "destroy" the variable when you defined a function. They must have different names.

Use this:

```
import urllib.request  

    def readWordList():  

    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000")
    html = response.read()
    data = html.decode('utf-8').split()

    return data

    to_clean = readWordList() # Use a different name so it won't be replaced later by the function
        def clean(aList):   
        newList = []
        for word in aList: 
            if range(len(word)) >= 2:
                newList.append(word)
        return newList
    clean(to_clean)
```

Problem solves; now they have different names.

Comment: What does this add to the previous answers?  Call out your improvements.

Comment: @Prune, I think I made a better explanation so he would understand it better. But if you want... I can delete it...

Comment: Nope -- I wanted to make sure your improvements are obvious to later users.  SGITE (Slowest Gun In The East) is often useful on SO.