# How to implement method chaining of Selenium multiple WebDriverWait in Python

Tags: python, selenium, lambda, method-chaining, webdriverwait

I am looking to implement *method chaining* of Selenium WebDriverWaits.

To start with, this block of code implementing a single *WebDriverWait* works perfect:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']"))
element.send_keys("method_chaining")
```

As per as my current requirement I have to implement chaining of two [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) instances as the idea is to fetch the element returned from the first *WebDriverWait* as an input to the (chained) second *WebDriverWait*.

To achieve this, I followed the discussion [method chaining in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172934/method-chaining-in-python) tried to use the use *Python*'s [**`lambda`**](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function through **method chaining** using [Pipe - Python library to use infix notation in Python](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe).

Here is my code trial:

```
from pipe import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
element = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until((lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']"))
        | where(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table[role='presentation']")))  
element.send_keys("method_chaining")
```

I am seeing an error as:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52456/devtools/browser/e09c1d5e-35e3-4c00-80eb-cb642fa273ad
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms\python_pipe_example.py", line 24, in <module>
    | where(lambda driver: driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[role='presentation']")))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pipe.py", line 58, in __ror__
    return self.function(other)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pipe.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    return Pipe(lambda x: self.function(x, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pipe.py", line 271, in where
    return (x for x in iterable if (predicate(x)))
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Followed the following discussions:

- [python3 TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633530/python3-typeerror-function-object-is-not-iterable)
- [TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable' Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340542/typeerror-function-object-is-not-iterable-python-3)

Still no clue what I am missing.

Can someone guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: *to implement WebDriverWait for two expected_conditions*... Which expected conditions?

Comment: @Andersson good question...(in my answer I assumed `presence_of_element_located` and `element_to_be_clickable`).

Comment: @DebanjanB In my answer, you can see some of your issues, I am sure you will have a more elegant way to implement it...

Comment: @Andersson Thanks for looking. I have updated the question for brevity. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: The question keeps changing, quite a moving target :). The latest edit is "as the idea is to fetch the element returned from the first WebDriverWait as an input to the (chained) second WebDriverWait." - but in your attempt sample you're not using the first element, the wait is based off `driver` - so it's from the top of the DOM.

Comment: @Todor There is no significant difference in the question with respect to the first version of this question. The requirement is clear _Method Chaining_ of _WebDriverWaits_ through _lambda_ expressions. The changes in the verbatim is to reduce the grey area and aiming for canonical answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

I don't know if it meet your requirement, but we need to create custom construct.

```
@Pipe
def where(i, p):
    if isinstance(i, list):
        return [x for x in i if p(x)]
    else:
        return i if p(i.find_element_by_xpath('//ancestor::*')) else None

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']") \
        | where(lambda y: y.find_element_by_css_selector("table[role='presentation']")))  

element.send_keys("method_chaining")
```

---

old:

---

I'm not an expert but I think maybe you misunderstand with how pipe work, by default it work to process previous value, for example

```
original | filter = result
[a,b,c] | select(b) = b
```

what you want maybe is `and` operator

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(
    lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[role='presentation']")
    and driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='email']"))
```

or selenium [ActionChains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) but no wait method, we need to extend it

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

class Actions(ActionChains):
    def wait(self, second, condition):
        element = WebDriverWait(self._driver, second).until(condition)
        self.move_to_element(element)
        return self

Actions(driver) \
    .wait(15, EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[role='presentation']"))) \
    .wait(15, EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']"))) \
    .click() \
    .send_keys('method_chaining') \
    .perform()
```

Answer (score 4):

As I gather your requirement is actually to have a `WebDriverWait` with two expected conditions, not precisely to use method chaining and the `pipe` library at all cost.

You can do that, by pushing the lambda expression syntax a bit. The cleanest solution is to make it an enumerable over function calls, and get the returned value of the one you need:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: (x.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']"), x.find_element_by_css_selector("table[role='presentation']"))[1])
```

With the index you'll receive the second tuple member, e.g. the `table` element.

The expression can be rewritten to a boolean:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']") and x.find_element_by_css_selector("table[role='presentation']"))
```

And you'll once again get the second element, the last part of the boolean. This implementation has some pitfalls though, when (ab)used with too complex boolean, so YMMV; I'd stick with the 1st one, the enumerable.

With this approach you get the benefits of `WebDriverWait` - if any of the calls in the tuple raises one of the handled exceptions there will be a rertry, etc.
There is one performance negative that comes out of this approach though - the call to the first method will be executed on every cycle, even if it has already passed successful and now the second condition is waited for.

---

And, here's a totally different alternative, the most clean solution - I see you're not shy to use xpath, so a pure xpath one.
As your aim is to get the `table` element, if and only if the `input` is present, this will do just that:

```
//table[@role='presentation' and ancestor::*//input[@id='email']]
```

This will select the `table` with the role. The other condition for it is to go up its ancestors - and the `ancestor` axis will go up to the top node in the DOM - and to find down from there an `input` element with that id attribute.

Thus if the `input` is still not present, the xpath will not match anything. The moment it's available, and there's also a `table` with that role value - it'll be returned.
Naturally, this selector can be used directly in the `WebDriverWait` with a single condition:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@role='presentation' and ancestor::*//input[@id='email']]"))
```

Comment: The first part of the answer was pretty much helpful. I have updated the verbatim of the requirement for more brevity. Can you have a re-look please?

Answer (score 1):

As your Error shows:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

This is because:

> where() method 
>       Only yields the matching items of the given iterable
>       for example `[1, 2, 3] | where(lambda x: x % 2 == 0) | concat => '2'`

Hope this answers *Can someone guide me where I am going wrong?*

**EDIT:**

If you want to use `pipe.where`:
so you can do that with the same code you have just with some changes:
Your `element` var should be something like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,15).until((lambda driver: driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='email']"))) \
       | where(WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[role='presentation']")))
```

But you can't do anything with the `element` because it is a *generator object*.

The best thing to do for *"to implement WebDriverWait for two expected conditions"* is just to have two line's of `WebDriverWait`!

Like this:

```
presentation_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table[role='presentation']")))
email_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']")))
email_element.send_keys("method_chaining")
```

Hope this helps you...

**Edit2**:

I think what you are looking for is to construct your one Pipe as shown [here](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe#constructing-your-own).

Comment: Thanks @MosheSlavin I have updated the question for brevity. Can you please have a relook?

Comment: @DebanjanB I don't know if it's possible to do but you can try constructing your one Pipe...